# RAID no longer Mounts

Tags: mount, raid

I have a recently built (several weeks ago) Z370 HD3P PC with two RAID 1 arrays attached via the Intel RST hardware RAID. One is NTFS and the other Ext4. I noticed this morning that the Ext 4 RAID will not Mount any more but the NTFS one is fine running 4.15.043. If I boot to 4.15.042 everything works perfectly again and both arrays mount.
I installed some Ubuntu updates yesterday, is it possible anything in these could have broken this? I have done various tests and am sure there are no hardware problems or corruption to the filesystem on the array that wont mount now. The error I get is the standard wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock message (udisks-error-quark, 0).
Does anyone have any suggestions what's happened please?

```
mount: /mnt/d64c011c-c55a-48fc-8e35-4ec8b2366e36:
wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md124, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

$ dmesg
...
[ 3723.564227] EXT4-fs (md124): bad geometry: block count 488377889 exceeds size of device (488377856 blocks)
```

After some research I tried to mount the array manually using a couple of backup superblocks but got exactly the same result.

Comment: Can you add the error message when you manually mount the ext4 partition (e.g. `mount /mnt/raidext`). Also post the output of `dmesg` after the failed mount.

Comment: mount: /mnt/d64c011c-c55a-48fc-8e35-4ec8b2366e36: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md124, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

Comment: dmesg has the last entry as:[ 3723.564227] EXT4-fs (md124): bad geometry: block count 488377889 exceeds size of device (488377856 blocks)

Comment: What I can't get my head around is why if I boot version 4.15.042 it still works perfectly.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115698/fix-ext4-fs-bad-geometry-block-count-exceeds-size-of-device

Comment: Thanks for the info. I searched extensively for a clue as to why it might have happened but so far have drawn a blank.  Fixing it was simple as I could boot the previous kernel (042) and recover the files to the NTFS volume then return to 043 and reformat the volume after which of course it mounted and I could copy back the files from the NTFS volume. It seems something recently changed in 043 or on my instance of it to cause this, which is worrying but I don't have the in depth knowledge of Ext4 to track it down, or the time to be honest.

Comment: I just checked the last kernel changes (https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/bionic/log/)... but there are on changes for RAID or ext.

Comment: I doubt RAID is relevant given its uses the Intel RAID in this case. I did see some Ext4 items in the November 9th batch which I may only have recently installed. Anyhow if it isn't being seen by anyone else I must assume it was something specific to my machine and so far its continued to work correctly since applying the reformat fix a few days ago. Thanks for looking, I doubt I will get to the root cause of this one.